# Working with android JNI

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I'm using a open source project in Gitgub.

I have to change package name of it.

Primary part of archArm.c function code source is :

```
 jstring
  Java_com_github_hiteshsondhi88_libffmpeg_ArmArchHelper_cpuArchFromJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
```

And primary ArchArmHelper.java is :

```
package com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg;

class ArmArchHelper {
static {
    System.loadLibrary("ARM_ARCH");
}

native String cpuArchFromJNI();

boolean isARM_v7_CPU(String cpuInfoString) {
    return cpuInfoString.contains("v7");
}

boolean isNeonSupported(String cpuInfoString) {
    // check cpu arch for loading correct ffmpeg lib
    return cpuInfoString.contains("-neon");
 }
}
```

Now I edited part of archArm.c function to :

```
 jstring 
 Java_com_emad_amerian_libffmpeg_ArmArchHelper_cpuArchFromJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
```

And I edited my ArchArmHelper.java to :

```
package com.emad.amerian.libffmpeg;
class ArmArchHelper {
static {
    System.loadLibrary("ARM_ARCH");
}

native String cpuArchFromJNI();

boolean isARM_v7_CPU(String cpuInfoString) {
    return cpuInfoString.contains("v7");
}

boolean isNeonSupported(String cpuInfoString) {
    // check cpu arch for loading correct ffmpeg lib
    return cpuInfoString.contains("-neon");
 }
}
```

I can to build my APK file successfully but when run Launch my project return error :

```
02-28 23:29:20.001 15094-15094/com.emad.amerian.sampleffmpeg E/art: No   implementation found for java.lang.String   com.emad.amerian.libffmpeg.ArmArchHelper.cpuArchFromJNI() (tried   Java_com_emad_amerian_libffmpeg_ArmArchHelper_cpuArchFromJNI and Java_com_emad_amerian_libffmpeg_ArmArchHelper_cpuArchFromJNI__)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export the function using the JNIEXPORT and JNICALL macros:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_emad_amerian_libffmpeg_ArmArchHelper_cpuArchFromJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
```

This makes the function visible in the symbols table of the library so that the Java VM can link it.

Comment: Thanks, I tested it but returned same Error

Comment: Did you rebuild the .so file? Were there any warnings or errors?

Comment: I'm using ready project. so how can to rebuild .so file? the project link is : github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Comment: Install the Android NDK and add the NDK folder to your path. Then go into the jni folder of your project and run the ndk-build batch file. Copy the .so file from jni/lib folder to wherever it belongs in your project (probably main lib folder)